# What's the best way for my backend server to notify my iPhone app when something happens?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

When something happens on the backend, I want to let my users' iPhone app know of this change. (The app is currently open, not in the background...if that makes it any easier).

Should I install Firebase just to achieve this? What are other ways?

Push notifications is just the UI for the user...am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Apple Push Notification Service.  If a Push Notification arrives while your app is in the foreground, it gets passed to you directly, rather than triggering a UI event.  Last I knew, you can only have 1 notification outstanding at a time, so you should not depend on it for passing content, but just use it as as signal to query your server.  With iOS 8 you can use background notifications, that do not require any user permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use Push Notification. Because it will save battery power on the device.

Comment: Do push notifications send an alert to the user? Or can I do it in the background only?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Apple Push Notification Service (APNS) to send push notifications to the user.

You could ask your server frequently about changes or use a blocking function in seperate Thread to handle events.

What kind of events are we talking about?
As Black Frog said, PNS is the easiest and most battery saving idea.

Comment: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)